# PhpStorm: what is the best way to handle "return value is expected to be ..." warning?

Tags: php, inheritance, phpstorm, phpdoc

My PHP code is structured to be something like follows (this structure is unchangeable):

```
class BaseFooClass {
}

class ChildFooClass1 extends BaseFooClass {
}

class ChildFooClass2 extends BaseFooClass {
}

//... (there are like a hundred child foo classes)

class BaseBarClass {
    protected function getFooBase($input) : BaseFooClass 
    {
        $class = "ChildFooClass" . $input;
        return new $class();
    }
}

class ChildBarClass1 extends BaseBarClass {
    public function getFoo() : ChildFooClass1 
    {
        return $this->getFooBase(1);
    }
}
```

Now in the `getFoo()` function in `ChildBarClass1`, PhpStorm will give the warning "Return value is expected to be 'ChildFooClass1', 'BaseFooClass' returned " and it correctly does so.

However I want a clean code with no warning without changing this structure.

I tried the following by adding PHP doc:

```
    public function getFoo() : ChildFooClass1 
    {
        /** @var ChildFooClass1 $foo **/
        $foo = $this->getFooBase(1);
        return $foo;
    }
```

However this time it gives a different warning "Unnecessary local variable" and ask me to inline it back.

Is there a good way to get rid of the warnings?

EDIT: the following is tried too but still the warning of "Return value is expected ..." is showing up.

```
    /**
     * @return ChildFooClass1
     */
    public function getFoo() : ChildFooClass1 
    {
        return $this->getFooBase(1);
    }
```

Comment: *"However this time it gives a different warning "Unnecessary local variable " and ask me to inline it back."* Such a warning should no longer be showing up in a future 2022.1 version (maybe even in the upcoming 2021.3 version, but rather unlikely) https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-59730

Comment: What if you add the @return in a docblock? Fairly certain that should work

Comment: @Martijn I tried it too (actually PhpStorm auto-generated it) but unfortunately the warning is still there. I guess at worst I can wait until the future version and take the unnecessary warning for now, at least it's not forever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your code `BaseBarClass::getFooBase()` returns a `BaseFooClass` while `ChildBarClass1::getFoo()` *wants* to return a `ChildFooClass1`.

This violates php's [Covariance/Contravariance](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.variance.php) rules, by which you can only return a more specifc type not a more general type, of which PhpStorm correctly warns you about.

So you could either adhere to this rule (*good*) and refactor your code or suppress the error (*bad*).

E.g.:

```
// corrected type:
class ChildBarClass1 extends BaseBarClass
{
    public function getFoo(): BaseFooClass
    {
        return $this->getFooBase(1);
    }
}

// error suppressed:
class ChildBarClass1 extends BaseBarClass
{
    public function getFoo(): ChildFooClass1
    {
        /** @noinspection PhpIncompatibleReturnTypeInspection */
        return $this->getFooBase(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer and explanation of the rule. Is there a good way for my case to adhere to the rule? My `getFooBase` function does a lot of common things that are dependent on the child class content.

Comment: The Foo class has a protected array member variable that are hard-written in each ChildFooClass file and different for each ChildFooClass (if you know Laravel it's the "$fillable" in Model, and getFooBase is taking values from database and fill it into it $fillable and then return the object) and the getFooBase loops through the array and do things with this array. The final new() takes as parameter the result of the looping. Therefore it looks like I either will need to write repetitive code in each separate child foo class or not adhering to the covariance rule. Is there a good way to do it?

Comment: Maybe you could ask a new question with a more concrete example of your problem? Preferably with the information you added with your comment? Until then, there are a few things you could try. 1) Ask yourself if it's actually important to type the return to `ChildFooClass1`? Does the caller of `getFoo()` need to know it's a `ChildFooClass1` or would a `BaseFooClass` suffice? 2) Without seeing an actual example, it's hard to be sure, but often an abstract method in the parent class (to be implemented in the child classes) helps in these kind of situations.

Comment: 3) Maybe you don't actually need inheritance, and could use a trait instead?

Comment: @cr001 why not just remove ` : BaseFooClass` part from `protected function getFooBase($input)` signature? In your **simple** example code it is not actually used anywhere (the results of `getFooBase()` call -- it is returned from a function straight away. A more concrete/real example is needed to give you any better advice.

Comment: I have posted a new question here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70170892/is-there-a-good-way-to-adhere-to-the-covariance-contravariance-rule-while-not-wr