# Is there a good way to adhere to the covariance/contravariance rule while not writing repetitive code?

Tags: php, inheritance, covariant-return-types

I have some code like follows. I tried to simplify the code to be easy to understand as much as possible.

```
class BaseFooClass {
    protected $keys = [];
    private $map = [];
    public function __construct($keyValuePairs) {
        foreach($this->keys as $key => $value) {
            $this->map[$key] = $keyValuePairs[$key] ?? null;
        }
    }
}

class ChildFooClass1 extends BaseFooClass {
    protected $keys = ['foo1_a', 'foo1_b'];
}

class ChildFooClass2 extends BaseFooClass {
    protected $keys = ['foo2_a', 'foo2_b', 'foo2_c'];
}

//... (there are like a hundred child foo classes)

abstract class BaseBarClass {
    protected $classIndex;
    protected function getFooBase(int $dataIndex) : ?BaseFooClass 
    {
        // GetRemoteData is assumed to be a global function, the important thing here is the retrieved data depends on classIndex and dataIndex
        // If $classIndex is 1, the $keyValuePairs will look like ['foo1_a' => value1, 'foo1_b' => value2] where value1 and value2 depend on $dataIndex
        $keyValuePairs = GetRemoteData($this->classIndex, $dataIndex);
        if (checkDataIntegrity($keyValuePairs)) {
            $class = "ChildFooClass" . $this->classIndex;
            return new $class($keyValuePairs);
        }
        return null;
    }
}

class ChildBarClass1 extends BaseBarClass {
    protected $classIndex=1;
    public function getFoo(int $dataIndex) : ?ChildFooClass1 
    {
        // this line violates covariance/contravariance rule
        return $this->getFooBase($dataIndex);
    }
}

class ChildBarClass2 extends BaseBarClass {
    protected $classIndex=2;
    // input to getFoo in each BarClass can be different
    public function getFoo($someInput) : ?ChildFooClass2
    {
        $dataIndex = $this->calculateDataIndex($someInput);
        // this line also violates covariance/contravariance rule
        return $this->getFooBase($dataIndex);
    }
}
```

The three critertia I want to meet are:

(1) I want to make sure ChildBarClass1::getFoo only returns ChildFooClass1, but also making sure BaseBarClass::getFooBase only returns a class that inherits BaseFooClass. Rule of thumb: make type declaration as strict as possible.

(2) I want to make sure there is no repeated code. I don't want to call GetRemoteData and checkDataIntegrity in every single getFoo function. In fact there are much more stuff than these two in the real code as well.

(3) I want to adhere to the covariance/contravariance rule. Currently the third last line shown in the code violates this rule as it uses a function that returns the parent foo class.

I cannot seem to come up with a good solution. Anything I came up with will either break either rules or make the code look like a "hack" and really ugly. If anyone can provide a good way to solve this problem, without breaking any of the three criteria or changing the general structure (i.e. every Foo class has a corresponding Bar class handling creating the Foo object), I will really appreciate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given your code, you could simply remove the return type from `getFooBase()` (or with php v8, make it `: mixed`). The method is not part of the public api. And as such there's no real loss here.

As your `getFoo()`s return values are typed individually, you'd get a type error anyways if whatever `getFooBase()` returned wasn't suitable.

Comment: Downvoted for finding an excuse to eliminate the problem in the specific case instead of answering the question in the general case where the specific elimination opportunity doesn't necessarily arise. 99% of people who find your answer will be frustrated.